Quickfixn - How to catch "connection refused"?
It happened in my QuickFixN application that FIX communication was not working. In logs I could see:
<event> Connecting to {IP} on port {Port}
<event> Connection failed: Connection refused {IP}:{Port}

Note that these logs are coming from the library.
After I restart my application (with the same configuration), FIX restarted working.
I am wondering if there is a way to catch this "connection refused" event. My application is based on the tutorial. If I could catch it, I could maybe try to recreate the SocketInitiator.
Thanks in advance!

No, there isn't.  In the source for SocketInitiator, the error is caught so that it can be logged.
The thought is that this is probably not recoverable without dev intervention.  (As a maintainer of QF/n, I'm open to hearing about cases where this would be incorrect.)

Thanks! I do not think it is incorrect, but for me it is important to be somehow informed about it, so that we can do some operations to try to recover it. We are on Azure and those logs do not reach our Analytics resource. Maybe due to log level, because we have a minimum log level of Information. And without logs there, we cannot set alerts. Again, it would be important to be informed in code. Maybe an event when connection fails?
